# How do I show the Phone Input softkeyboard when my activity starts?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Between the Activity tags in my AndroidManifest.xml I have :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateVisible"
```

So when my activity starts the soft keyboard comes up:

[image]

Is there not something I can add to make the phone input keyboard come up instead? Or how would I do it? Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT**

For the sake of clarity to this question I'm adding this 'edit'.

First of all, thanks for all the answers below.

However, my objective is to have no Edittext Visible on the screen, at first. The Phone Input soft keyboard comes up as soon as the activity starts and when the user starts
to type then the Edittext will become visible, with the text being typed.

I tried making the Edittext invisible, and then make it visible when user starts typing, but the problem is an invisible edittext can't have the focus,

So, `android:inputType="number"`  was having no effect.  And neither was: `edittext.requestFocus();` Because the `edittext` was invisible.

What I ended up doing eventually was something very simple, setting width and height to 0dp in my xml like :

```
android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:inputType="number" />
```

That way, the `edittext` can get focus with

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

as soon as the activity is created, and `inputType = "number"` is recognised.

The next thing I'll do is increase the size of the edittext as soon as a key is hit on the soft keyboard, so users can see it.

I'll put all this in as an answer so it might be helpful to other users. +1 for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

or

```
android:inputType="number"
```

to your View in your XML layout.

You should have some View in your code where you can give input like **EditText** or **AutoCompleteTextView** for changing the type of the keypad.

For example -

```
       <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an `EditText` in the `Activity` which you show once your app is started, you can add below XML Attribute to your `EditText`.

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Check developer [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) for other input types in case if you need.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest file set the property in activity,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

and then in your xml where your EditText set the property,

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 1):

**first of all take an EditText in your xml**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number" />
```

**use this piece of code in the onCreate method of your activity !**

```
    EditText etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);

    etPhoneNumber.requestFocus();

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

This works for me very well ! Hope it works for you too !

Let me know if this works ! :)

Comment: Thanks, but just the first part of your code, 
EditText etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);
 etPhoneNumber.requestFocus();
seems to do the job just fine - in conjunction with android:inputType="number" in my XML. Can you see any issues with leaving the last part of your code out? Hate having code around if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The objective is to have no `Edittext` Visible on the screen, at first.

The Phone Input soft keyboard comes up as soon as the activity starts and when the user starts
to type then the `Edittext` will become visible, with the text being typed.

I tried making the Edittext invisible, and then make it visible when user starts typing, but the problem is an invisible edittext can't have the focus,

So, `android:inputType="number"`  was having no effect.  And neither was: `edittext.requestFocus();` Because the edittext was invisible.

What I ended up doing eventually was something very simple, setting width and height to 0dp in my xml like :

```
android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:inputType="number" />
```

That way, the edittext can get focus with

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

as soon as the activity is created, and `inputType = "number"` is recognised.

The next thing to do now is increase the size of the edittext as soon as a key is hit on the soft keyboard, so users can see it.